# Господа верстальщики, помогите разобраться с z-index

Tags: z-index, html, css

Доброе время суток, как выставить так скажем "абсолютный" z-index не зависимо от блоков?

Есть вот такой пример: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/Rgsfx/

Есть ли возможность сделать текст (UL) поверх всего, именно при такой верстке?
Дело в том что NAV должен двигаться вместе с UL, разделять их совсем не хочется. А section это прозрачная PNG которая накладывается поверх "желтого блока" но текст должен быть доступен.

Comment: а почему nav не присвоить z-index: 999? ul он же относительно nav позицонируется.

Comment: тогда section закроется полностью, нужно чтобы section перекрывал только nav, но НЕ перекрывал UL. при этом UL это ребёнок NAV :(

Comment: возможно конечно. Тогда с nav нужно убрать position: absolute; и поставить на ul.

Comment: Да почти так как нужно, остальное додумаю сам.Спасибо, сделайте ответом, я приму.

Comment: не вижу, что тут можно сделать ответом. Рад был помочь.